# UK Student Visa application Mistake

Tags: visas, uk, study

Here is my situation. I'm applying for a UK student visa. I filled up my application, paid, and printed my application. Upon rechecking it I noticed that in my travel history I mentioned that I traveled On July 21, 2009 to Egypt but the exact date is July 27, 2009. July 21, 2009 was the date the visa was given to me. Will this be considered as deception by the Entry Clearance? If I can correct it, how can I do that?

Comment: I read the entry in the link above. Does it mean that I can make a pen and Ink correction before giving it to TLScontact?

Comment: LOL! That is not deception. Don't be so paranoid.